# bundle install fails after using RailsInstaller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, batch-file

I have installed Ruby using RailsInstaller. The location of the install is `C:\RailsInstaller`. When I create a new project with RubyMine I can not start the web service as I can't even run `bundle install`:

```
C:\Users\Cameron\Documents\Development>bundle install
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I have the following that pertains to Rails in my `PATH`:

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\DevKit\bin
```

I have done some research online and a lot of people are claiming that it is `rails.bat` is incorrect. Here is the original file at `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\rails.bat`:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
@"C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe" "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/rails" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```

I have tried to change to this, with no luck:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
ECHO.This version of Ruby has not been built with support for Windows 95/98/Me.
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"%~dp0ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```

I have attempted to manually initialize DevKit and got the following:

```
C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit>ruby dk.rb init
[INFO] found RubyInstaller v2.2.1 at C:/Ruby22

Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated
'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all
of the installed Rubies you want enhanced by the DevKit.

C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit>ruby dk.rb install
[ERROR] Skipping invalid directory 'C:/Ruby22'
```

Going into `C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\config.yml` and changing `- C:/Ruby22` to `- C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0` and then rerunning:

```
C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit>ruby dk.rb install
[INFO] Skipping existing gem override for 'C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0'
[WARN] Skipping existing DevKit helper library for 'C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0'
```

What do I need to do / change so that I can use my local environment for RoR development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to manually initialize DevKit:

```
ruby dk.rb init
ruby dk.rb install
```

And make sure that the config.yml (inside DevKit) points to the right place before running `dk.rb install`:

```
---
- C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby<version number>
```

EDITED: As @Cameron pointed on comment, it might be necessary to run `ruby dk.rb install -f` after modifying `config.yml`

I had the same problem and, in my case, the `config.yml` was pointing to somewhere else other then Ruby installed by RailsInstaller.

Comment: I have attempted that and updated the question with my results.

Comment: I believe you just fixed the problem. Have you tried creating a new Rails test app, just to see if the creating and the bundling works?

Comment: It did not fix it but by running this did: `ruby dk.rb install -f`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 3 folders to your `PATH` on Windows:

1. C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;
2. C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin;
3. C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\DevKit\bin;

Comment: Hmm... that's weird. Did you uninstall existing Ruby and install Ruby & DevKit provided by RailsInstaller?

Comment: Yes. I used to have Ruby installed on this machine at `C:\Ruby22`. Now i only have Ruby installed at `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0`

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same issue as your case, I solve it as below:

Open `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\bundle.bat`,

Change : `"C:\Users\emachnic\GitRepos\railsinstaller-windows\stage\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe"` to `@"%~dp0ruby.exe"`

Go to your workspace and `%>bundle install`

It would be ok!